# Play Framework Ebean two ManyToMany relations return same data

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2, playframework-2.3, ebean

My code looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class Document extends Model
{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "developers")
    private Set<Tester> developers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "testers")
    private Set<Tester> testers = new HashSet<>();
}
```

I am using the `JoinTable` annotation otherwise I end up with the same join table for the many-to-many relation. This works well and I get two tables generated (developers and testers).

I am even able to save the data properly. Setting the developers and/or testers and then saving the document entity works properly.

Now the problem is that the moment I do something like:

`Document.find.all()` to get the available Documents, the developers and the testers fields return the same data, despite the data being different in the database. Doing `document.getDevelopers()` and `document.getTesters()` return the same data with `getDevelopers()` always *hiding* the `getTesters()` data.

Is this some bug/limitation in the Ebean ORM?

I am using Play 2.3.8

Comment: It is a bug in EBean. You can see also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24099008/ebean-multiple-manytomany-delivers-strange-behavior)

Comment: @rtruszk I actually looked for something similar but did not find that one. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly **fetch**ing the fields returns the proper data.

Just define own find method like this:

```
public static List<Document> findAll() {
    return Ebean.find(Document.class)
                .fetch("developers")
                .fetch("testers")
        .findList();
}
```

Still wondering if there are better ways...

Answer (score 0):

I find a Solution that works for me without fetching other tables and without get exceptions..

instead using the list itself declare an entity that hold the list.

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
ForeignStories foreignStories = new ForeignStories();
```

where ForeignStories is..

```
@Entity
@Table(name="foreign_stories")
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class ForeignStories extends Model {
    @Id
    @NotNull
    Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Story> foreignStories = new ArrayList<Story>();
}
```